# Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 SPI bus not registering on custom Poky OS [Yocto]

Tags: spi, device-tree, yocto, compute-module-4

I am trying to get a `MCP2515` (CAN-bus IC that works on SPI) to work on a `Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 (8GB eMMC, No Wifi, 4GB RAM)`.

I have been able to get the module working on a regular `Raspberry Pi 4B`. Although not yet on the Compute module with my custom OS.

I have been building my own Pi image with `Yocto` (and the `Poky` distro) with a `64-bits` version of the OS. The `meta-raspberrypi` layer has been used to get the correct `BSP (Board support package)` for the hardware I'm using.

The kernel I'm currently using is: `Linux raspberrypi4-64 5.10.81-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 22 14:00:03 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

As far as I am concerned, SPI should get enabled when I add the following lines to `/boot/config.txt`:
`dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=22`
`dtparam=spi=on`

The `mcp2515-can0.dtbo` file is present in the `/boot/overlays` folder.

When the Pi boots, I can't seem to find an entry for SPI in `/dev/` (checked with `ls | grep spi`)

The `/sys/bus/spi/devices` folder is also completely empty.

The kernel does not seem to give any errors regarding SPI (checked with `dmesg | grep spi`).

So I started to think that the some other dtbo files are absent or something along those lines. So I added some deprecated lines to the `/boot/config.txt` file, to see if that makes a difference:
`dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay`
`dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835`

Which seems to change nothing (as expected, since they are deprecated overlay files, which aren't present in the newest RPi Firmware files: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot/overlays)

There also are no blacklisting files present in `/etc/modprobe.d` or in `/etc/modules`

Then  finally, I have also tested the `spi0-1cs.dtbo` file with the following line (note, I commented all the other config.txt lines, so this line is the only one present): 
`dtoverlay=spi0-1cs,cs0_spidev`, still not even the slightest hint that the SPI bus is present.

EDIT: I also found out that when I list all kernel modules with `lsmod`, that only the `sch_fq_codel` and the `ipv6` modules are loaded. When I check the /proc/modules file, it also only shows those 2 entries.

The `/lib/modules/5.10.81-v8/kernel` folder only seems to contain entries for `net` modules, although the `/lib/modules/5.10.81-v8/modules.builtin` file does have entries regarding SPI. (pointing to `kernel/drivers/base/regmap/regmap-spi.ko` and `kernel/drivers/mfd/stmpe-spi.ko`, which both don't seem to exist.) So it seems like the kernel modules are not available in this build? Does anyone know how I could force these modules into my build?

Also, there is no `/etc/modules` file present in my build by default. If I understand correctly it will imitate calling `modprobe $MODULE` for each line entry. When I try to run `modprobe spidev` (or `modprobe spi-dev` for that matter, or `modprobe i2c-dev`) it gives an error `modprobe: FATAL: Module spidev not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.81-v8` which sounds logical, since those files are not present in my filesystem.

I am running out of ideas to try. Does anyone else maybe have a idea on what I could try?

Thanks in advance.

With kind regards,
Mats de Waard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright ladies and gents...

I got it to work!

Turns out Yocto does not add the kernel modules to the final `image.tar.bz2`, but keeps in in a seperate `modules.tgz` file. I was manually copying the `image.tar.bz2` contents and the `bootfiles` contents onto my CM4 (so this did not include the modules).

Manually adding the files to the eMMC of the Raspberry Pi CM4 seemed to work after I updated the kernel dependencies with `depmod`. After updating these dependencies, the `modprobe spidev` command works correctly, and I can now access the SPI device under `/dev/spidev0.0` and `/dev/spidev0.1`!

It might be possible that this problem would be bypassed, if I had learned to use the .WIC files, delivered with a Yocto build, instead of copying the files manually to the eMMC.

Hopefully my findings will save someone some headaches :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add few details to the accepted solution. I fixed by appending all the required kernel modules in my custom image recipe:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " iproute2"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-spidev"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-spi-bcm2835"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-can"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-can-dev"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-can-raw"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kernel-module-mcp251x"
```

Note that this depends by the hardware you are using. In my case it is an MCP2515 connected to a Raspberry CM4.